# Msi setup showing File in use message on uninstallation

Tags: c#, wix, windows-services, wix3.6

I have developed an msi setup using WIX which consists of a desktop application as well as a windows service and both are running on C# .Net 3.5 framework. My windows service starts only when any user logs into the system which triggers the desktop application to start. The windows service is made to run as Local System. **The msi setup is getting installed successfully at Win-8, Win-7 and Windows-XP but showing "File In Use" message while doing uninstallation even the service is not removed from the SCM.** I have given the below codes at the OnStop() method of the service and inside the WIX page respectively.

onStop() method:

```
Process[] workers = Process.GetProcessesByName("filename");
workers[0].WaitForExit(1000);
workers[0].Kill();
workers[0].Dispose();
workers[0].Close();
```

Product.wxs inside WIX:

```
<ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstaller" Name="Servicename"    
DisplayName="service display name" Description="service description" 
Start="auto" Account="LocalSystem" ErrorControl="normal"  
Type="ownProcess"></ServiceInstall>
<ServiceControl Id="ServiceInstallerControl" Name="Servicename" 
Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall"   Wait="yes" />
```

The service is not removed from the SCM at all and the below popup message is displaying at the time of uninstallation process.

[image]

I have worked around with the WIX to solve the problem but unable to do so.

Any kind of help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How does the service run the desktop application?  If the service starts the desktop application process synchronously, the service won't return control back to the Service Control Manager (SCM) until the desktop application is terminated.  Might explain why the un-install can't stop/remove the service.  Running an uninstall with logging might offer some insight into what is going on: `msiexec /l*v Remove.log /x InstallPackage.msi`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to create custom action that handles the uninstall.You can create a batch file with the uninstall details , and then simply execute the batch file from the custom action( as a process).Its good practice to create installation and uninstall batch files with your service.